# Cannot load module after updating php to 5.5

Tags: 12.04, drivers, apache2, php

after updating php and restarting the apache2 i get this error:

```
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_R.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules
/mod_R.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
```

This module is the rApache. Before that update everything was fine on my ubuntu 12.04. I am very new to ubuntu.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score -1):

that's not a problem with php5, but the php5.5 PPA also updates apache2 package from apache2.2 to apache2.4, so you will probably need to update your rApache as well.

Ondrej.